# Compute Stock Option price using Binomial Tree in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to compute the price of an option and the code below is based on a text that i found in one of the threads. I would now like to visualize the binomial tree such that at each node the following are displayed:

1) Stock Price
2) Option Price as we traverse back from the end i.e. the payoffs in case of an European Option
3) Payoff in case of early exercise i.e. American Option

The code computes the values correctly, but I am having a challenge in displaying the same visually. I thought of converting the numpy array of arrays to a df but I get weird results.

Can someone help please?

This sets the key parameters to compute the price

```
""" Store common attributes of a stock option """
import math
class StockOption(object):
    def __init__(self, S0, K, r, T, N, params):
    self.S0 = S0
    self.K = K
    self.r = r
    self.T = T
    self.N = max(1, N) # Ensure N have at least 1 time step
    self.STs = None # Declare the stock prices tree

    """ Optional parameters used by derived classes """
    self.pu = params.get("pu", 0) # Probability of up state
    self.pd = params.get("pd", 0) # Probability of down state
    self.div = params.get("div", 0) # Dividend yield
    self.sigma = params.get("sigma", 0) # Volatility
    self.is_call = params.get("is_call", True) # Call or put
    self.is_european = params.get("is_eu", True) # Eu or Am

    """ Computed values """
    self.dt = T/float(N) # Single time step, in years
    self.df = math.exp(-(r-self.div) * self.dt) # Discount factor
```

This is the heart of the exercise where all the Future Stock prices are computed and then the payoffs are computed by traversing back

```
""" Price a European or American option by the binomial tree """
from StockOption1 import StockOption
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class BinomialTreeOption(StockOption):
    def _setup_parameters_(self):
        self.u = 1 + self.pu # Expected value in the up state
        self.d = 1 - self.pd # Expected value in the down state
        self.qu = (math.exp((self.r-self.div)*self.dt) -
               self.d)/(self.u-self.d)
        self.qd = 1-self.qu



    def payoff(self):
        self._setup_parameters_()

        self.STs = [np.array([self.S0])]
        for i in range(self.N):
            prev_branches = self.STs[-1]

            st = np.concatenate((prev_branches*self.u,
                             [prev_branches[-1]*self.d])) 
            self.STs.append(st)




## Compute payoff at the last node
        payoffs = np.maximum(0, (self.STs[self.N]-self.K) if self.is_call
                          else (self.K-self.STs[self.N]))





        for i in reversed(range(self.N)):
            # The payoffs from NOT exercising the option
            payoffs = (payoffs[:-1] * self.qu +
                   payoffs[1:] * self.qd) * self.df



            # Payoffs from exercising, for American options
            if not self.is_european:
                early_exer_payoff = \
                        (self.STs[i] - self.K) if self.is_call \
                        else (self.K - self.STs[i])

                payoffs = np.maximum(payoffs, early_exer_payoff)


        return payoffs[0]


""" Price an option by the binomial CRR model """
from BinomialAmericanOption1 import BinomialTreeOption
import math

class BinomialCRROption(BinomialTreeOption):
    def _setup_parameters_(self):
        self.u = math.exp(self.sigma * math.sqrt(self.dt))
        self.d = 1./self.u
        self.qu = (math.exp((self.r-self.div)*self.dt)-
                   self.d)/(self.u-self.d)
        self.qd = 1-self.qu



#### Option price
from StockOption1 import StockOption
from BinomialAmericanOption1 import BinomialTreeOption
from BinomialCRROption1 import BinomialCRROption


crr_amoption= BinomialCRROption(50, 60, 0.05, 4, 4,{"sigma": 0.3,
                                               "is_call": True,
                                               "is_eu": False})


print(crr_amoption.payoff())
```

Comment: Hi, do you have an example of the output you would like to have? It is like a tree?

Comment: Hi Meng - please see the illustration at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TrinomialTreeOptionPricingMethod/